# Evaluating Ancestry DNA match to clarify Half Sibling relationships?

Tags: dna

I did the Ancestry DNA an had a match of 1671 to a person I did not know. My sister did the test and matched him at 1251. My father believes he has a son he does not know and the stories seem to add up. My question is, from everything I have read my sister's numbers should be higher in order for him to be a half sibling.

Answer (score 2):

I am assuming that you and your sister match as expected, as either paternal half-siblings or full siblings.

According to the data that Blaine Bettinger has gathered through his Shared cM Project, yes, the shared DNA between your sister and your potential new half-brother falls outside the range for a half-brother: [Shared cM Project for 1251 cM](https://dnapainter.com/tools/sharedcmv4/1251). However, if you look at that page, it lists a 28.26% probability for some additional potential relationships, including half-sibling. This potential relationship comes with the following note:

> this relationship has a positive probability for 1251cM in thednageek's table of probabilities, but falls outside the bounds of the recorded cM range (99th percentile)

You can read more about this in thednageek's post [The Limits of Predicting Relationships Using DNA](http://thednageek.com/the-limits-of-predicting-relationships-using-dna/).

I think the best next step would be to ask your father to do a DNA test. Then you'd get a solid answer about how your father and this unknown person are related.